# Graphs with chromatic number $(\chi(G) \ge 3 )$ other than odd cycle (Triangle free)

Tags: graphs

[Chromatic number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChromaticNumber.html) denoted by $\chi(G)$ of graph $G$ is the minimum number of colours required to properly colour the given graph.

For ODD Cycle chromatic number is 3 and it does not contain triangle as a subgraph. I thought about complete , star, wheel graphs etc, but they don't satisfy the conditions.

I am looking for examples of graphs of $\chi(G)$ $\ge 3$, **but does not contain a triangle or odd cycle as subgraph**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a graph contains no odd cycle then it is bipartite and so 2-colorable.